# Use Linux with line breaks

Tags: linux, perl, text, command-line-interface

I am using this:

```
perl -pi -w -e 's/SEARCH_FOR/REPLACE_WITH/g;' *.txt
```

and the SEARCH_FOR input has line breaks. For example:

SEARCH_FOR:

```
I want to get
rid of this text
in multiple files
```

REPLACE_WITH:

[Nothingness / 0 bytes]

Comment: Very good. So what happens when you do this? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-0` command line parameter changes input record separator `$/`, and `-0777` sets it to `undef` which effectively puts `readline()` into slurping whole file at once, so you can successfully apply multi line substitution regex.

Answer (score 1):

Since `perl -p` reads, processes and prints one line at a time, the multi-line search-for pattern is never going to match a single line of input.  Therefore, you're going to have to find a way to make Perl read multiple lines at a time.